# Can not convert from System.Lazy<IARepository> to System.Lazy<IGenericRepository>

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, repository-pattern, lazy-initialization

I am trying to achieve lazy initialization with SimpleInjector and using Generics I am getting an error in my AService.cs while sending Lazy inside base constructor. I have read that Lazy don't support covariance, But my question is how to get any workaround to use generics with IoC and Lazy.

AService.cs

```
public class AService : GenericService, IAService
{
    private readonly Lazy<IARepository> aRepository;
    public AService(Lazy<IARepository> aRepository) : base(aRepository)
    {
        this.aRepository = aRepository;
    }
}
```

IAService.cs

```
public interface IAService : IGenericService
{
}
```

IGenericService.cs

```
public interface IGenericService
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

GenericService.cs

```
public class GenericService : IGenericService
{
    private readonly Lazy<IGenericRepository> genericRepository;
    public GenericService(Lazy<IGenericRepository> genericRepository)
    {
        this.genericRepository = genericRepository;
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        genericRepository.Value.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Bindings in Simple Injector

```
container.Register<Lazy<IARepository>>(
    () => new Lazy<IARepository>(container.GetInstance<ARepository>));
container.Register<Lazy<IBRepository>>(
    () => new Lazy<IBRepository>(container.GetInstance<BRepository>));
container.Register<Lazy<IAService>>(
    () => new Lazy<IAService>(container.GetInstance<AService>));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117619/covariant-use-of-generic-lazy-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is answered here:

[How to downcast an instance of a Generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144902/how-to-downcast-an-instance-of-a-generic-type)

tl;dr:

> The compiler can't know that `Bar<T>` can be cast to `Bar<Foo>` in this case, because it's not generally true. You have to "cheat" by introducing a cast to object in between:
>
> `return new FooBar<Foo>( (Bar<Foo>)(object) bar);`

So you should be able to achieve this by doing:

`public AService(Lazy<IARepository> aRepository) : base((Lazy<IGenericRepository>)(object)aRepository) { }`

Comment: Getting Unable to cast object of type 'System.Lazy`1[Services.Repos.IARepository]' to type 'System.Lazy`1[Services.Repos.IGenericRepository]'.